# What if Guru's order is contrary to scriptures should it still be followed?

Tags: dharma-shastras, guru

Namaste,
Can a student obey a Guru's order if Guru orders something which is against scriptures?
Please provide scriptural proof in this regard..

Comment: Follow your guru, if you don't feel satisfied then leave. But don't get struck between guru and scripture.

Comment: A shishya must stick to his gurus words unwaveringly. But this holds true only till upasana krama. If some padhati is different in some Aagam shastra and ur guru is teaching differently follow ur Guru's words. That's Kula dharma. Apart from that, if Guru is faulty and asking to do paapkarma just move away, until the words accords to Shastras. As a personal experience had been in touch earlier with a guru who said to enjoy sensual pleasures as much as one want. This contradicts to Shastras and therefore found futher loopholes in them. So, here it requires Shishya's self analysis on his Guru.

Comment: If your Guru is really jeevanmukta and u have realized that, and has always abided to scriptures but this is the 1st call when he said to do something differently, do that. Since, sometime Gurus choose very different path to teach shishyas based on our nature. So, what here is important is **guru's conduct**, if Srì Guru is pristine and really bhagwatprapt, these things of shastras don't contradict, since any words from such Jeevanmukta is Shastra itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your Guru is wrong then leave him.

**Freedom to change Guru**

> But should you have a Guru who does not have the knowledge and always
> create doubt, no blemish attaches to you if you go to another.

**Kularnava Tantra, Guru-Shishya, Readings by M.P. Pandit**

Answer (score -1):

Guru's orders or teachings that are contrary to scriptures or contrary to dharma, need not be followed.

An example is from [Srimad Bhagavatam 7.5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128374.html), where Prahalada does not approve of the teachings of his gurus.

> 1. As is reported, the glorious Kāvya (Śukra) was selected by demons to fill the office of the royal priest. His two sons, Śaṇḍa and Amarka, stayed near the palace of the king of Daityas (Hiranyakasipu).

> 2. They taught the course of studies (in politics and such other sciences) to Prahlāda and other eligible Asura students sent to them by the king, even though Prahlāda was expert in philosophy.

> 3. **Whatever was taught there by the teacher, he (carefully) listened and reproduced it. But he did not approve of the teaching that was on the false notion of distinguishing between (man and man) as friends and enemies.**

Another description of this account is given [here](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/5/) -

> **Prahlāda Mahārāja did not carry out the orders of his teachers, for he was always engaged in worshiping Lord Viṣṇu.** As described in this chapter, Hiraṇyakaśipu tried to kill Prahlāda Mahārāja, even by having a snake bite him and by putting him under the feet of elephants, yet he was unsuccessful.

> Hiraṇyakaśipu’s spiritual master, Śukrācārya, had two sons named Ṣaṇḍa and Amarka, to whom Prahlāda Mahārāja was entrusted for education. Although the teachers tried to educate the boy Prahlāda in politics, economics and other material activities, he did not care for their instructions. Instead, he continued to be a pure devotee. **Prahlāda Mahārāja never liked the idea of discriminating between one’s friends and enemies. Because he was spiritually inclined, he was equal toward everyone.**

> .......Hiraṇyakaśipu affectionately took his son Prahlāda on his lap and then inquired from him what the best thing was that he had learned from his teachers. As usual, Prahlāda Mahārāja began praising the nine processes of devotional service, such as śravaṇam and kīrtanam. Thus the King of the demons, Hiraṇyakaśipu, being extremely angry, chastised the teachers, Ṣaṇḍa and Amarka, for having wrongly trained Prahlāda Mahārāja. **The so-called teachers informed the King that Prahlāda Mahārāja was automatically a devotee and did not listen to their instructions.**